# Why is the static keyword needed in this template code?

Tags: c++, templates, static

Working on a simple example for template functions. The code compiles and works as expected. But my question is why "static" is required in both "Cmp" and "Lit"? Otherwise, it will not compile?

Thanks a lot!

```
template<class T> class Cmp{
public:
    static int work(T a, T b) {
        std::cout << "Cmp\n";
        return 0;
    }
};

template<class T> class Lit{
public:
    static int work(T a, T b){
        std::cout << "Lit\n"  ;   
        return 0;
    }
};

template<class T, class C>
int compare(const T &a, const T &b){
    return C::work(a, b);
}


void test9(){
    compare<double, Cmp<double> >( 10.1, 20.2);
    compare<char, Lit<char> >('a','b');
}
```

Comment: Note that the whole thing could be expressed without any classes, simply with functions and function templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `static` is required here is that in the `compare` template function, you have this line:

```
return C::work(a, b);
```

The syntax `C::work(a, b)` here means "call the function `work` nested inside the class `C`.  Normally, this would try to call a member function without providing a receiver object.  That is, typically the way you'd call a function `work` would be by writing

```
C myCObject;
myCObject.work(a, b);
```

In this case, though, we don't want to be calling a member function.  Instead, we want the function `work` to be similar to a regular function in that we can call it at any time without having it act relative to some other object.  Consequently, we mark those functions `static` so that they can be called like regular functions.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

`C::work(a, b)` names a static member function `work()` of class `C`.